# How do i extract the variables passed through a builtin library in robotframework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a robot file where I will pass the

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds | 2 min | 5 sec
```

Would I be able to to handle/extract the value/parameters passed programatically rather than using custom keyword and additional variables something very similar to

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
bi = BuiltIn()
bi.get_variable_value('${timeout}') .
```

is there any possibility to get the passed values like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no built-in way to do that. You'll need to write your own custom keyword.